# After installing vnc4server on my server and Vinagre on my local machine, I can't ssh my server using command line

Tags: ssh, vnc, vinagre

After installing `vnc4server` on my server and `Vinagre` on my local machine, I can't `ssh` to my server using the command line on my machine (but `ssh` using `Vinagre` is OK). Nothing appears in `/var/log/auth.log` at the server when I try to `ssh` to server using command line. The debug output look like this:

```
zw@zw-Inspiron-3442:~/.ssh$ ssh -vvv bigfish@192.168.1.123
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/zw/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.123 [192.168.1.123] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/zw/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/zw/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/zw/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/zw/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/zw/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/zw/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/zw/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/zw/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/zw/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

client ssh_config file:

```
19 Host *
 51     SendEnv LANG LC_*
 52     HashKnownHosts yes
 53     GSSAPIAuthentication yes
 54     GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

server sshd_config file:

```
# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to outline the steps you took to install and configure `vnc4server` and `vinagre` (or link to the instructions you followed, if applicable). Was creation of an RSA keypair part of the process? Did you modify any SSH configuration files?

Comment: You can get more details from this question(http://askubuntu.com/questions/839025/i-cant-ssh-to-server-using-my-account-but-a-new-account-works). I followed http://askubuntu.com/questions/127466/blank-screen-with-vnc-server to config vnc4server.  No RSA keypair was created. Now I uninstall vnc4server and vinagre, it still does not work.

Comment: Please include /home/zw/.ssh/config

Comment: It is not related to /home/zw/.ssh/config.  I have already tried to empty this file.